# Why I can't enter on site where on other tab I start long script on tihs site?

Tags: php

I open web-page on my site via browser, for example test.php, which contains long-time script (5min for example). When I open on other tab for example index.php of this site in the same browser there is failure (long loading) while long script on test.php finished on previous tab. I need to open other browser to enter on index.php.

Why I can't open index.php on the same browser? It tied with session, and it block my next requests?

Comment: Are you using [the built-in PHP development server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)? If not, what webserver are you using?

Comment: @ceejayoz nginx + apache

Comment: Using *both* of those is pretty uncommon. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes. I use bitrix framework and it has such architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If your test.php script uses sessions, that may be (b)locking your other requests until it finishes processing.

If this is the case, you should use

```
session_write_close();
```

in your test.php, to prevent further session locking.